# Application is visible on active applications but restarts when i tap on it

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have made an application in Ionic with geolocation in background.
It works perfect, but randomly after some time when in background and phone is inactive, it stops running.

If i click the active applications I can see it still there, but by tapping on the application, it seems to restart/reload rather than resume it.

What does this mean, that the application crashed or something ? If so, why it is still viewable on the active applications?

I know the application is not actively running in background any more, since it doesn't not display any more the warning that this application is using battery in background mode etc.

Comment: The image you see in the recents list is just a screenshot of the last time it was used. If your app has not been used for a while and other things have been done during that time the OS will remove it from memory so that more memory is available for other things causing the restart that you see. You should have a foreground service running for your geolocation so that the OS does not kill your service

Comment: @tyczj you seem to understand exactly my problem. So if the app by clicking active apllications acts as a restart, it means that my application was killed in background. My application when in background sends coordinates to an API, but probably the OS thinks it's doing nothing so it kills it randomly. How can I overcome this problem ?

Comment: I just told you, your service that sends the GPS points needs to be a foreground service. Your app may still be restarted but the service should still be running in most cases